# godaddy www. not working

Tags: nginx, dns, digital-ocean

I got a domain name with godaddy - http://craberg.com , and I point it to my server which is on digitalocean.com , I use easyengine.io to easily install wordpress , also I use nginx NOT apache, so the problem is that when I go to http://craberg.com it loads fine , but http://www.craberg.com version does not work ,error-

> www.craberg.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

I tried to do forwarding on godaddy's side , but I could not do it , because I'm forwarding it to http://craberg.com and it complains -

> You may only apply a single forward per subdomain.

so I don't know how to fix the problem and where is the problem on the server or with godaddy , also godaddy changed their interface so I can't even view CNAME

Comment: What type of record is `WWW` in your DNS? Make sure it's a `CNAME` pointing to your domain. Also, what does your nginx server config look like? You may need to allow the server name to look something like `server_name craberg.com www.craberg.com;`.

Comment: In my nigix.conf file there is no such lines at all `server_name craberg.com www.craberg.com;` even there is no `server_name` line , I found the config file in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` , about CNAME I'll contact godaddy support coz they change interface and I don't even see CNAME option there :( , so should I add `server_name craberg.com www.craberg.com;`  to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` ? should I add it to the first line ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was on my hosting side : I went to digitalocean->networking->mydomain and added CNAME record : www | @ , and it worked ! 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/adding-a-subdomain-a-record-or-cname